# Query fails when column is named 'DATE' (column name)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In Oracle 10g I have a table named `MYDB_PUNCHTIMEDETAILS` and it has a column named `DATE` of type `TIMESTAMP`. Whenever I try to execute the statement below:

```
SELECT date FROM mydb_PUNCHTIMEDETAILS
WHERE  date like '19-01-15 11:56:39.000000000 AM'
```

it generates following error:

> Error at Line: 51 Column: 9
>   ORA-00936: missing expression

Can anyone suggest how to get the data or execute the query? I am new in Oracle.

Comment: Is the column named `"DATE"` (uppercase) or `"date"` (lowercase)? You should be aware that this is not normally allowed as a column name, as it is a keyword used for both a datatype and a literal expression (e.g. `date '2018-08-03'`). The only way to name a column like this is to force it by enclosing the name in double quotes when creating the table and every time you refer to it.

Comment: What should `like` mean for a timestamp comparison? Did you mean `=`?

Comment: its in lower case "date"

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me your very crucial time.Really you all are so appreciable

Answer (score 3):

Put 'date' in double quotes,

```
SELECT "date" FROM mydb_PUNCHTIMEDETAILS WHERE "date" like '19-01-15 11:56:39.000000000 AM'
```

Also see [the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/212981/25)

**Update**

While oracle's implicit data type conversion allows for comparing timestamps to strings, the where clause will probably not work as expected since `LIKE` compares strings: It depends on format used in the the implicit conversion from timestamp to varchar2 which appear to differ between column values and literals (that might be the result of an optimization when parsing). Conceptually, approximate matching on split-second precision might not be the intention at all.

Either choose exact comparison (comparison of timestamp values)

```
select "date" from test WHERE "date" = TIMESTAMP'19-01-15 11:56:39.000000000';
```

or construct a `like` argument matching the desired precision:

```
-- ok (precision in comparison: minute)
select "date" from test WHERE "date" LIKE REPLACE(TIMESTAMP'19-01-15 11:56:39.000000000', '39.000000000', '%');
```

The cleanest way would be to convert between data types explicitly and specify format/precision:

```
select "date" from test WHERE TO_CHAR("date", 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') LIKE TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP'19-01-15 11:56:39.000000000', 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

The updated sql fiddle shows these and some more variations (some working, some not)

(Thanks to @WilliamRobertson to have pointed out the issue discussed.)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me your very crucial time.Really you all are so appreciable

Comment: The `like` part is still a problem, because `like` compares strings and `"date"` is a timestamp.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks for pointing that out. I have complemented the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions:

- Use naming standards - don't name your table columns like "Date","Number" and etc - be more specific, like "Creation_date","Transaction_date"
- Use alias, like:

  `select
    mpd.date
  from
    mydb_punchmedetails mpd`

Comment: When I am using alias its generating error as : ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 51 Column: 11

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me your very crucial time.Really you all are so appreciable

Comment: Curious to see your SQL statement with alias - maybe skipped something. If you are willing to dig deep - post it and we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that this is not normally allowed as a column name, as it is a keyword used for both the datatype and in literal expressions (e.g. `date '2018-08-03'`). The only way to name a column like this is to force it, by enclosing the name in double quotes when creating the table and every time you refer to it, using the exact same upper/lower case letters.

Obviously this is going to cause extra work forever, as well as being confusing because `date` and `timestamp` are two different datatypes.

This fails:

```
create table mydb_punchtimedetails
( date timestamp );

ORA-00904: invalid identifier
```

You can force Oracle to skip its normal validation:

```
create table mydb_punchtimedetails
( "DATE" timestamp );

insert into mydb_punchtimedetails values (timestamp '2015-01-19 11:56:39');
insert into mydb_punchtimedetails values (timestamp '2018-08-03 14:10:00');

select d."DATE" from mydb_punchtimedetails d
where  d."DATE" = timestamp '2015-01-19 11:56:39';
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,finally you solved my problem now and obviously has saved my a lot of time.Thank you so much.